# If $z_{n+1}=\frac{27}{\overline{z_{n}}}+6$ and $z_1 = 3 + 6i$, then find $z_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, induction

> Let the complex sequence $\{z_{n}\}$ satisfy $z_{1}=3+6i$, and 
>   $$z_{n+1}=\dfrac{27}{\overline{z_{n}}}+6.$$
>   Find the $z_{n}$.

My idea: since
$$z_{n+2}=\dfrac{27}{\overline{z_{n+1}}}+6=\dfrac{27}{\dfrac{27}{z_{n}}+6}+6?$$

So I can't. Thank you

Comment: Do you need an expression for $z_n$ or its limit, as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 4):

**1.** First terms of the sequence:

$$
z_1 = 3+6i;
$$
$$
z_2 = \dfrac{39}{5}+\dfrac{18}{5}i = {\large 9}-\dfrac{6}{5}+\dfrac{18}{5}i;
$$
$$
z_3 = \dfrac{363}{41}+\dfrac{54}{41}i = {\large 9} - \dfrac{6}{41}+\dfrac{54}{41}i;
$$
$$
z_4 = \dfrac{3279}{365}+\dfrac{162}{365}i = {\large 9} - \dfrac{6}{365}+\dfrac{162}{365}i;
$$
$$
z_5 = \dfrac{29523}{3281}+\dfrac{486}{3281}i = {\large 9} - \dfrac{6}{3281}+\dfrac{486}{3281}i;
$$
$$
...
$$

**2.** 
Now we can fill the pattern:
$$
z_n = {\large 9} - \dfrac{12}{9^{n-1}+1} + \dfrac{4\cdot 3^n}{9^{n-1}+1} i.\tag{1}
$$

**3.**
It remains to apply math. induction to prove $(1)$.

Denote 
$a_n = \mathbf{Re} z_n, ~~~ b_n = \mathbf{Im} z_n$.

Show that

$$
a_n = 9-\dfrac{12}{9^{n-1}+1} =  \dfrac{9^n-3}{9^{n-1}+1}; \tag{2}
$$
$$
b_n = \dfrac{4\cdot 3^n}{9^{n-1}+1}. \tag{3}
$$

If it holds for some $n$, then

$$
z_{n+1} = \dfrac{27 (a_n+ib_n)}{a_n^2+b_n^2}+6;
$$

$$
a_{n+1} = \mathbf{Re} z_{n+1} = \dfrac{27 a_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2}+6;
$$
$$
b_{n+1} = \mathbf{Im} z_{n+1} = \dfrac{27 b_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2};
$$

$$
a_n^2+b_n^2 = \dfrac{(9^n-3)^2+ 16\cdot 9^n}{(9^{n-1}+1)^2} = \dfrac{9^{2n}+10\cdot 9^n+9}{(9^{n-1}+1)^2} = \dfrac{(9^n+1)(9^n+9)}{(9^{n-1}+1)^2} = \dfrac{9(9^n+1)}{9^{n-1}+1};
$$

$$
a_{n+1} = \dfrac{27 a_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2}+6 = \dfrac{27(9^n-3)}{9^{n-1}+1} \cdot \dfrac{9^{n-1}+1}{9(9^n+1)} +6 =
\dfrac{3(9^n-3)+6(9^n+1)}{9^n+1} = \dfrac{9^{n+1}-3}{9^n+1};
$$
$$
b_{n+1} = \dfrac{27 b_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2} = 27 \cdot \dfrac{4\cdot 3^n}{9^{n-1}+1} \cdot \dfrac{9^{n-1}+1}{9(9^n+1)} = \dfrac{4\cdot 3^{n+1}}{9^n+1}.
$$

That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

Clearly
$$
z_{n+2}=\dfrac{27}{\overline{z_{n+1}}}+6=\dfrac{27}{\dfrac{27}{z_{n}}+6}+6=
\frac{27z_n}{6z_n+27}+6=\frac{63z_n+162}{6z_n+27}.
$$
Setting $x=z_n=z_{n+2}$ and solving the resulting equation we obtain that $x=9$ is a solution (a fixed point). In particular, subtracting the fixed point we get
$$
z_{n+2}-9=\frac{3(z_n-9)}{2(z_n-9)+27}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{z_{n+2}-9}=\frac{2(z_n-9)+27}{3(z_n-9)}=\frac{2+\frac{27}{z_n-9}}{3}.
$$
Setting
$$
w_n=\frac{3}{z_n-9},
$$
you obtain that
$$
w_{n+2}=9w_n+2,
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{w_{n+2}}{3^{n+2}}=\frac{w_n}{3^n}+\frac{2}{3^{n+2}}.
$$

Comment: Hello,can you  post you following  answer? Thank you,because I fell very very ugly.

Comment: Dear @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, can you tell me what is your intuition behind your substitution?

Answer (score 2):

If we can solve
$$
w_{n+1}=\frac{27}{w_n}+6\tag{1}
$$
then
$$
z_n=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
w_n&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\overline{w}_n&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$
$(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
w_{n+1}w_n-6w_n-27=0\tag{3}
$$
If we shift $(3)$ with $u_n=w_n+a$ to get rid of the constant, we can get an equation that we can divide by $u_{n+1}u_n$ to get a linear equation in $\frac1{u_n}$:
$$
\begin{align}
(u_{n+1}-a)(u_n-a)-6(u_n-a)-27&=0\\
u_{n+1}u_n-au_{n+1}-(a+6)u_n+a^2+6a-27&=0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Letting $a=3$, we get $a^2+6a-27=0$. Then $(4)$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}u_n-3u_{n+1}-9u_n=0
&\implies\frac1{u_{n+1}}=\frac19-\frac13\frac1{u_n}\\
&\implies\frac1{u_{n+1}}-\frac1{12}=-\frac13\left(\frac1{u_n}-\frac1{12}\right)\\
&\implies\frac1{w_{n+1}+3}-\frac1{12}=-\frac13\left(\frac1{w_n+3}-\frac1{12}\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{w_n+3}-\frac1{12}=\left(-\frac13\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac1{w_1+3}-\frac1{12}\right)\tag{6}
$$
Using $(2)$ and $(6)$, we get $z_n$.

---

$w_1=3+6i$. Plugging this into $(6)$ gives
$$
w_n=\frac{12\left(1+i\left(-\frac13\right)^{n-1}\right)}{1+\left(\frac19\right)^{n-1}}-3\tag{7}
$$
Then $(2)$ gives
$$
z_n=\frac{12\left(1+i\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}\right)}{1+\left(\frac19\right)^{n-1}}-3\tag{8}
$$

Comment: thank you, then can you post your result?

Comment: @chinamath: I just plugged in the initial conditions. I assume that is what you want.